# Upload an image to Microsoft Computer Vision API through volley on Android using octet-stream

Tags: android, computer-vision, byte, android-volley

I´ve been trying to make a request to Microsoft Computer Vision API using volley on android, but I want to upload the image from the phone and not just send an URL. The reference from the API (https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) says to put the Content-Type on application/octet-stream and in the body it just says "[Binary image data]".

I´ve tried sending the image as a byte array (byte[]) but I keep getting the response 400 (which stands for InvalidImageFormat or Size).
It works fine if I use the URL method, but I need to upload the image.

[This is the only information that the documentation gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TadGm.png)

This is the code I've been using:

```
String URL = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories&language=en";
            StringRequest apiRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    RespuestaApi.setText("Respuesta: " + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    RespuestaApi.setText("Error: " + error.toString());
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    headers.put("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", SubKey);
                    return headers;
                }
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImgTemp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    return imageBytes;
                }

            };
            VolleySingleton.getInstancia(PruebaApi.this).agregarACola(apiRequest);
```

My Bitmap works fine by the way.
This is the error that the logcat gives me:

```
 E/Volley: [41310] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories&language=en
```

[This is the reference for the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJMbJ.png)

So, finally, what do I have to do to send the proper image format that the API requires?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `retrofit` to do that. I was also getting the same error, but finally I managed to make it work.

Add `retrofit` dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

Now coming back to how to upload it.

Create an Instance.

```
interface ServiceToCall {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: c6e79ef6f90xxxxxx6743xxx1778be5"
    })
    @POST("describe/")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Body RequestBody body);
  }
```

Now, you will need to pass the file (the image file which has to be uploaded) to the request. For that, first you need to store that file somewhere.

This will be my `onActivityResult` function.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        newImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        //Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        for (File temp : newImageFile.listFiles()) {
            if (temp.getName().equals("image.jpeg")) {
                newImageFile = temp;
                Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imageHolder.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`newImageFile` is my file. Now in order to upload it, I will call another function.

`private static final String uriBase_retrofit = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/";`: This is the url.

```
public void testRetroFit(Context context, File t) {

    //System.out.println("File to be uploaded is : "+filetoupload.toString());
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    // Change base URL to your upload server URL.
    ServiceToCall service = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(uriBase_retrofit).client(client).build().create(ServiceToCall.class);

    File file = new File(String.valueOf(t));
    stringname = file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("Absolute path is : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    RequestBody te = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),file);
    retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = service.postImage(te);
    req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                String abc = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("response is : " + response.body().string());
                System.out.println("Legth is : "+abc.length()+"and value is : "+abc);
                JSONObject output = new JSONObject(abc);
                JSONObject des = output.getJSONObject("description");
                JSONArray cap = des.getJSONArray("captions");
                JSONObject cap_description = cap.getJSONObject(0);
                String cap_textres = cap_description.getString("text");
                Double cap_conf = cap_description.getDouble("confidence");
                result_api.setText("Result is : "+cap_textres);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("raw is : "+response.raw());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

This one worked for me.

P.P.S. Learnt after a hard way that `response.body().string()` can only be consumed once.